# Need for automatic voltage regulator when the utility's generation capacity increases

Tags: voltage

Is there a need to regulate the incoming voltage from the utility companies in my country if the generation capacity has been significantly increased? I would be using a static voltage regulator for the regulation.

Comment: All caps? Really? Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: We don't appreciate shouting here.

Comment: @JoeHass: Fixing the OP's mess is a bad idea for two reasons.  First, that's his job.  If he doesn't want to fix it, I want the arrogant tone to persist so that it can be dealt with appropriately.  You editing the post only changes the post, not his attitude.  Second, by editing the post you are denying the OP the ability to show he can change his attitude.  This post is now closed because there was no evidence that the OP ever changed his attitude from shouting at us.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree with your sentiment on this. If we're not careful EE.SE will become no better than Yahoo Answers or some such dreck. In my defense, someone else changed the all-caps title before I got to it, I just tried to clean up the language.

Answer (score 4):

The grid company should take care of this - it's their duty to maintain the voltage within the expected range. They will monitor current consumption and adjust generation so that they more or less match and the voltage is within range.

So if they introduce several new power plants you shouldn't bother any more than you would bother before that - the grid will regulate the generation so that it matches the consumption anyway. With more generation capacity they even have more capabilities for that - lower risk of grid overload and so less reason for undervoltage.